# AngularJS pass string as function to use at ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I want to assign a javascript function to ng-click which name is sourced by a rest service.

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('url')}" data-ng-repeat="menu in mb.data">
   <a href="{{menu.href}}" data-ng-click="{{menu.javascript}}">{{menu.label}}</a>
</li>
```

Sadly the angularjs parser throws an exception if one use {{ }} inside of ng-click. So I have tried several workarounds like using a callback function

```
  <a href="{{menu.href}}" data-ng-click="call(menu.javascript)">{{menu.label}}</a>
```

But none of my ideas succeeded. How can I assign a javascript functions name in ng-lick? Btw. the function itself is part of the $scope.

Edit- Here is the controller:

The "$menu" service is simply a get rest request. The request result is a json object and only holding string values. In the current issue the result for menu.javascript is "loginModal()".

```
.controller('HeaderController', function($scope, $http, ModalService, $menu, $routeParams) {
    $scope.loginModal = function() {
        console.log("modal", ModalService);
        // Just provide a template url, a controller and call 'showModal'.
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "/modals/login.modal.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            // The modal object has the element built, if this is a bootstrap modal
            // you can call 'modal' to show it, if it's a custom modal just show or hide
            // it as you need to.
            console.log(modal.element);
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                console.log(result ? "You said Yes" : "You said No");
            });
        });
    };

    $menu.get($routeParams, function(data){
        $scope.menu = data;
    });
})
```

Edit 2:

Interestingly when I use {{menu.javascript}} then the correct string "loginModal()" is available in the DOM. But the angular parser stopped there due to errors.

Comment: Use simple data-ng-click="menu.javascript"

Comment: just use this without any bracket ng-click="yourFunctionOnScope()"

Comment: yes data-ng-click="menu.javascript" compiles but does not call the script ...

Comment: What I believe is you have to use $compile service in order to use ng-click working. still I'm not sure about it.

Comment: can you provide more info about `menu.javascript` function?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do something like this

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <button ng-click="callFunction('testClick')">CLICK ME</button>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.callFunction = function (name){
        if(angular.isFunction($scope[name]))
           $scope[name]();
    }

    $scope.testClick = function(){
        alert("Called");
    }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13252/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried this one. Sadly It only works if use use fixed Strings. Which means "testClick" can not be a value of varibale.

Comment: @KIC in your case it would be `data-ng-click="callFunction('{{menu.javascript}}')"`

Comment: yes, data-ng-click="callFunction(menu.javascrpt)" works, I forgot to remove the () in my rest response. thx!

Comment: if I need pass callFunction into this module as isolated scope

Comment: Isolated scope will only come into the picture when you have directive.. Not sure whats ypu question?

Comment: Hey @PankajParkar can you help me same logic with ng-model. Right now if I pass any string in ng-model it is not parsing as ng-model and not updating any value related to model.  <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" ng-model="tableHeader.model" > now this is parsing as string

Comment: Can you please open a question on Stackoverflow with full explanation, I'll help you out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hashmap notation accessing the property of 'this' object (which, in this case, is $scope):

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('url')}" data-ng-repeat="menu in mb.data">
   <a href="{{menu.href}}" data-ng-click="this[menu.javascript]()">{{menu.label}}</a>
</li>
```